PFSense on Proxmox can't reach internet
Attempting to create a second router using PFSense.
The first router is a standard edge router.
The second router is inside a physical hypervisor machine running Proxmox.
Proxmox is connected to a switch connected to the edge router port with subnet 10.0.5.0/24
I would like to put PFSense as my second router inside the Proxmox hypervisor.
Recently set up a PFSense VM and can use it to ping the entire 10.0.5.0/24 subnet but NOT the internet or any other subnets
I have no firewall rules on my edge router
Proxmox is connected to a switch that is connected to the main edge router. Here are my settings
EDGE ROUTER
Edge Router WAN: DHCP from ISP
Edge Router Port Subnet: 10.0.5.0/24

PROXMOX INTERFACES (TOTAL): 3
eno1
enp2s0f0
enp2s0f1

PROXMOX BRIDGES
vmbr0 (MAINTENANCE)
    port: en01
    CIDR: 10.0.5.2/24
    Gateway: 10.0.5.1
vmbr1 (WAN)
    port: enp2s0f0 (UP)
    CIDR: blank
    Gateway: blank
vmbr2 (LAN)
    port: enp2s0f1 (UP)
    CIDR: blank
    Gateway: blank

PFSENSE VM
Hardware/Bridge: vmbr1
Hardware/Bridge: vmbr2

vmbr1 (vtnet0): 10.0.5.3/24
vmbr2 (vtnet1): 192.168.1.1/24
IP Type: Static IPv4

ERROR
ping 1.1.1.1
sendto: No host to route


Set the static default route towards the first "Internet router" and set a static route to 10.0.0.5/24 for the second router. What you want to know is: What is Routing?

I solved the problem of reaching the internet from the 192.168.1.0/24 network by setting an upstream gateway of 10.0.5.1. I can ping the internet and other subnets. However I can NOT use my main desktop to ping my new router. I attempted to create a static route on my edge router. Here are my settings.
Destination Network: 192.168.1.0/24
Gateway IP: 10.0.5.3
Note: I also tried 10.0.5.1 for the gateway but that did not work

Set Upstream Gateway to 10.0.5.1
